# Jaxb: Generating XML with different root element included in class which is being marshalled?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I am trying to create Companies House XML using JAXB  which has following format

```
<GovtTalkMessage  schemaLocation="schema1" xlmns="" xlmns:bs= "" xlmns:gt="">  
    <Header>    ....    </Header>    
   <Body>
       <FormSubmission schemaLocation="schema2" xlmns="" xlmns:xx="">
          .....
         <CompanyIncorporation schemaLocation="schema3" xlmns="" xlmns:yy="">
                 ...
          </CompanyIncorporation>
        </FormSubmission>    
   </Body> 
</GovtTalkMessage>
```

XML structure has been generated correctly apart from **schemalocations and xlmns**, schemalocation are not generation for any of the element where it should be and all xmlns of are visible in  `<GovtTalkMessage>` like

```
 <GovtTalkMessage  schemaLocation="schema1" xlmns="" xlmns:bs= "" xlmns:gt="" xlmns:xx="" xlmns:yy="">
```

`FormSubmission` and `CompanyCorporation` are generated as  `@XmlRootElement` by `xjc`.

Relevant @XmlSchema properties for xmlns and schemalocation value are added in package-info.java , also tried `@XmlElementDecl` as suggested [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html) but it did not help me.

CompanyIncorportion  **package-info.java** :

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "",   
    xmlns = {    
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk", prefix = ""),   
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" , prefix="xsi")
   }, 
    location = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v2-1/schema/forms/CompanyIncorporation-v2-6.xsd",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNSET) 
package com.xx.ch;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;   
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Gateway  package-info.java :

```
 @XmlSchema(namespace = "",   
        xmlns = {    
            @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", prefix = "dsig"),   
            @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/core", prefix = "gt"),   
            @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" , prefix="xsi")
       },   
        location = "http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd",
     elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)   

    package com.xx.gateway;  
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;   
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

FormSubmission  **package-info.java** :

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "",   
    xmlns = {    
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk", prefix = "bs"),   
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/Header", prefix = ""),   
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" , prefix="xsi")
   }, 
   // location ="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/Header http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v2-1/schema/forms/FormSubmission-v2-7.xsd" ,
       //@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/Header", 
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
    package com.xx.formsubmission;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

How can I generate `schemalocations` and `xmlns` where they are required by Gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem have been resolved by adding `@XmlAttribute` in corresponding `@XmlRootElement` classes.

```
@XmlAttribute(name="namespace_name")
public String namespace_value="xxxxxxxxxx";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `@XmlSchema` annotation on your package.

You can do this by adding `package-info.java` to the same package as your JAXB-annotated classes.

See the javadoc for examples:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html

Comment: I used `@XmlSchema` annotation inside  package-info.java , than after I was able to add  differnt xmlns in Xml element, problem is that all are generated at top elements not at other Tag where it should.  Schemalocation specified in package-info.java is not reflecting in generated XML.

Comment: Can you show your code? Are these different elements modelled by classes in different packages with their own package-info?

Comment: I have added package-info of the packages, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION` on the `Marshaller` to output the `schemaLocation`:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.example.com/address address.xsd")
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html

Comment: I have set schemalocation as  you suggested but I am able to set it only for <GovtTalkMessage> , I also need schemalocation for <FormSubmission> and <CompanyIncorpartion> tag along with various xmlns..

Comment: now instead of setting all the schemalocations and xmlnses in package-info.java , I am setting using @XmlAttribute which is working fine (inside Generated FormSubmission & CompanyIncorporation) , do you recommend this approach?